# prolog appending a list and a atom

Tags: prolog

I'm quite new to prolog, and I tried the following:

```
| ?- append([1],2,R).

R = [1|2]

yes
```

I have no idea what the notation `[1 | 2]` means. Trying to search this was painful, and I couldn't find any thing. I guess this is something like the lisp `(1 . 2)` resulted from `(cons 1 2)`. Can someone explain/reference to explanations about this?

If it matters to anyone, I'm using GNU-prolog version 1.3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The "General" form of `[H|T]`**

The list notation `[H|T]` is a syntactic sugar for `'.'(H,T)` which is the predicate defining the list by head and tail. For example, the list `[1,2,3]` could also be written `'.'(1,'.'(2,'.'(3,[]))).` (try, `X = '.'(1,'.'(2,'.'(3,[]))).` at the prolog prompt).

Since you seem familiar with Lisp, then in those terms, `X` is the `car` of the list `[X|T]` and `T` is the `cdr` of the list `[X|T]`.

`append/3` is typically used with list arguments, so to append an atom (called `atom`) to a list `L` and result being `R`, you'd do it like this:

```
append(L, [atom], R).
```

Or more specifically:

```
append([1], [2], R).
```

Yields: `R = [1,2]`.

In using `append/3` to define an implementation for `rev/2`, Clocksin & Mellish, *Programming in Prolog*, Fifth Edition, on p.157 state, in that context:

> By convention, the tail of a list is always a list.

If you're given a list, `L`, you can retrieve the head (car) and tail (cdr) by unifying it with the `[H|T]` form:

```
L = [H|T]
```

For example:

```
| ?- L = [1,2,3,4], L = [H|T].

H = 1
L = [1,2,3,4]
T = [2,3,4]

yes
| ?-
```

You can also pull off as may elements as you wish:

```
| ?- L = [1,2,3,4], L = [A,B,C|T].

A = 1
B = 2
C = 3
L = [1,2,3,4]
T = [4]

yes
```

It will fail if you try to do too many:

```
| ?- L = [1,2,3], L = [A,B,C,D|T].

no
```

The `[H|T]` form is handy in list processing predicates, particularly recursive ones:

```
my_list_process_predicate([H|T], [Result|Results]) :-
    % Do some stuff here, determing "Result" from "H" perhaps
    my_list_processing_predicate(T, Results).  % Get the rest of the results
                                               % from the rest of the list
```

If you were to write a list, say, `[1,2,3]` literally in the `[H|T]` form, you'd have any of the following equivalents:

```
[1,2,3|[]]
[1,2|[3]]
[1,2|[3|[]]]
[1|[2,3]]
[1|[2,3|[]]]
[1|[2|[3]]]
[1|[2|[3|[]]]]
```

**The list form `[H|T]` when `T` is an atom**

If you have a list `[X|T]`, means `X` is the head of the list, and `T` is the tail (usually a list itself). Although Prolog lets you construct such a list in which `T` is an atom, it doesn't seem commonly used, at least not as it is in Lisp. But, yes, `[1|2]` is indeed like `(1 . 2)` in Lisp. Lisp has some built-in functions which operate on lists of  `(a . b)` as key-value pairs, etc. Prolog doesn't have any built-ins that take advantage of the `[a|b]` structure that I'm aware of. They may have no more advantage over just using `[a,b]`. I also have searched for references to the `[a|b]` (or `[a1,...,an|b]`) form and found one in Clocksin & Mellish, p.53, in reference to an example unifying `[white|Q]` with `[P|horse]`:

> ...it is possible to use the list notation to create structures that
>   resemble lists, but which do not terminate with the empty list. One
>   such structure, `[white|horse]`, denotes a structure having head
>   `white` and tail `horse`. The constant `horse` is neither a list nor
>   the empty list, and ... such structures should be treated carefully
>   when used at the tail of a list.

The interesting thing is that most of the other built-in Prolog predicates that process a list will actually fail when given the `[a1,...,an|b]` form. For example, in GNU Prolog:

```
| ?- X = [1,2,3|4], length(X, L).

no
| ?- X = [1,2,3,4], length(X, L).

L = 4
X = [1,2,3,4]

yes
```

SWI Prolog throws an exception:

```
?- X = [1,2,3|4], length(X, L).
ERROR: length/2: Type error: `list' expected, found `4'
```

Similar results occur with other predicates. `maplist` will work on all of the elements of such a list but will ignore the tail atom. `append/3` will work as long as the first list does not have an atom as its tail.

The question about atom as tail in a list is a very good one. It seems Prolog allows it (you can unify `X=[1|2].` for example), and the `append/3` built-in handles it (perhaps inadvertently due to its simple design). I can be used as a valid form for data, `[a1,...,an|b]` and can be unified with forms that look like it. But most of the built-ins don't seem to consciously handle it properly. It also isn't acting as a generic 2-argument functor (attempt to unify `X=3|4.` would fail).

So, the form `[a1,...,an|b]` (where `b` is an atom) is a valid Prolog data structure, but it's behavior as a list must be handled carefully since most predicates assume that the tail of a list is a list, and that the "final" tail is the empty list, `[]`. So it can be legitimately used if desired, but with caution (as C&M indicate).