# Prolog empty list internal representation

Tags: prolog

I [read](http://www-users.york.ac.uk/~sjh1/courses/L334css/complete/complete2su6.html) that Prolog internally represents lists as right-branching trees.
So [a,b,c] is represented as:

[image: asda]

Are empty lists thus represented as a tree with a single root node (the empty list)?

And is a list containing an empty list represented as a tree with one root node and two leaf nodes, both empty lists? Like so:

```
    .
   / \
  /   \
 /     \
[]     []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'.'/2` functor in Prolog is actual list form, where the first argument is the head, and the second is the tail. So `[H|T]` is a syntactically convenient form of `'.'(H,T)`, and more specifically, `[H]` is a convenient form for `[H|[]]`, which is a convenient form of `'.'(H,[])`.

A list containing the empty list is a list of one element. In Prolog, it's representations are:

```
[[]]
[[]|[]]
'.'([],[])
```

And graphically, `'.'([],[])` would be as you showed:

```
    .
   / \
  /   \
 /     \
[]     []
```

The long form of the other list `[a,b,c]` you illustrated is:

```
'.'(a,'.'(b,'.'(c,[])))
```

The graphical form shown for lists is a visualization of this construct. And of course the Prolog interpreter recognizes this fundamental form:

```
| ?- X = '.'(a,'.'(b,'.'(c,[]))).

X = [a,b,c]

yes
| ?- X = '.'([],[]).

X = [[]]

yes
```

As CapelliC points out, the form `[]` isn't technically a list, from this representation perspective, but an atom that is used to represent an empty list recognized by Prolog built-ins as such.

```
| ?- [] = '.'(_,_).

no
| ?-
```

Prolog does respond "true" to `list([])` so that it can maintain this convention of it being an empty list representation in the built-in predicates.

And:

```
| ?- X = '.'(a,'.'(b,'.'(c,d))).

X = [a,b,c|d]

yes
| ?-
```

So here we used the atom `d` as the last argument instead of `[]` and it gave me a list, of sorts. However, most Prolog built-ins that work with lists will not work properly unless the "ultimate tail" atom is `[]`. See, for example, [prolog appending a list and a atom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22441538/prolog-appending-a-list-and-a-atom).

I realize that's a bit more than you asked for in your question. I got a little carried away. :)

Comment: @CapelliC I agree that's more accurate. I think that was the intent of the OP's ASCII art, but I added it to be clear. Thanks.

Comment: Change 'predicate' to 'functor' (first line).

Comment: @jschimpf thanks for catching that and being kind enough to point it out

Answer (score 1):

The empty list is a special *atom*, like the list functor (which usually is a dot).

From the GNU Prolog prompt, try

```
| ?- atom([]).

yes
| ?- atom([ ]).

yes
```

The `display/1` predicate allows to inspect the structure...

```
| ?- display([]).
[]

yes

| ?- display([[]]).
'.'([],[])

yes
```

then I would say the answer to your first question is no, while to the second one is yes...

Comment: Why is no the answer to the first question? Isn't that what the display command confirmed, i.e. it is just a single node (the empty list) ?

Comment: yes, but the node it's not a compound (a tree), but an atom. A big difference

Comment: @S0rin CapelliC is correct. The empty list is just an atom, and as I described in my answer, a convention in Prolog for representing an empty list.

Comment: Use `write_canonical/1` (ISO) in place of `display/1`.